# How do I pull an integer out of a NSDictionary and put it in an integer?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I've got an NSDictionary that was initialized with a plist that, among other things, contained count followed by 32 and I want to get at the value for count.

How?

I know how to get it into an object via

```
[dictionaryObjectName objectForKey:@"count"]
```

But to me, the value I'm obtaining is not an object.

If I have to specify an object, what would be the best one to use (FYI the value will always be unsigned) and I need to get it into a true int.

Do I do something like

```
NSNumber *num = [dictionaryObjectName objectForKey:@"count"];
int theValue = [num intValue];
[num release];
```

Is the release on num a good thing to do since this for an iPhone with no garbage collector?

Comment: int theValue = [num intValue]; // is an 'int'    AND  NSInteger theValue = [num integerValue]; // is an NSInteger

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you pull it out as an `NSNumber`, then grab the `int(eger)Value` but there's no need to release it.  You didn't retain, alloc, or copy the number, so you don't have to worry about releasing it.

Answer (score 28):

And nicer form is:

```
int theValue = [[dictionaryObjectName objectForKey:@"count"] intValue];
```

EDIT

Since I see that people still arrive to this page, let's clarify that these days you simply do

```
int theValue = [dictionaryObjectName[@"count"] intValue];
```